# Connecting azure data factory to Databricks SQL endpoint

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

Can we **connect to an Azure Databricks SQL endpoint from data factory**?
I am using the *odbc connector in data factory to create a linked service to the sql endpoint*, however I am failing to do so.
In the databracks sql endpoint UI, I am able to grab the jdbc based connection string, but I am not able to translate the same in odbc terms.

**We are restrained from accessing the Databricks workspace, so we cannot author Databricks notebook to access the sql endpoint. However, we only have read level access to the Databricks sql tables, so we are using odbc connector to setup the linked service in ADF.**

Any help is truly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to follow [documentation for JDBC/ODBC configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/integrations/bi/jdbc-odbc-bi#odbc-driver).  Just substitute specific parameters from the SQL Endpoint (like workspace URL, HTTP Path of the endpoint, etc.) into the connection string (I'm just not sure how to upload ODBC driver into Data Factory, something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/180866/how-to-install-a-odbc-driver-on-the-azure-integrat.html)):

```
Driver=<path-to-driver>;Host=<server-hostname>;Port=443;HTTPPath=<http-path>;ThriftTransport=2;SSL=1;AuthMech=3;UID=token;PWD=<personal-access-token>
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. I acknowledge the connection string format, however I am not able to get what should I put <path-to-driver> value.  More than knowing the value to put, I need to know where to find the value from. I have been checking the JDBC/ODBC properties of the cluster, but still couldn't decide on the driver path value

Comment: Path to driver is specific to ADF, not to the Databricks SQL. You need to look into something similar to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/180866/how-to-install-a-odbc-driver-on-the-azure-integrat.html

Comment: Thanks for that insight Alex, this issue is resolved

Comment: Should be "Driver=Simba Spark ODBC Driver;" (for Windows at least) - for specific "DB" can also add "Schema=<your-schema-name>;"